# How to connect two lines?

Tags: notepad++

Hello How to connect 2 lines seperated by an enter on notepad++ or Emeditor

I got something in format

```
JOHN
TRAVOLTA
Mark
Twain
Luis
Suaraz
```

I need them in format:

```
JOHN:TRAVOLTA
MARK:TWAIN
LUIS:SUAREZ
```

Its possible to do? someone can help me or give any advices?

Comment: Do you want to write a program for this? can you please specify some more details ?

Answer (score 0):

Using Find & Replace with a regular expression will do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.+)\R(.+\R?)`
- Replace with: `$1:$2`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
(.+)        # group 1, 1 or more any character but newline
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(.+\R?)     # group 2, 1 or more any character but newline and optional linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          # content of group 1 (i.e. the first word)
:           # a colon
$2          # content of group 2 (i.e. the second word)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In **EmEditor**, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show the the **Replace** dialog box, and enter:

**Find**:
`^(.+)\n(.+)$`

**Replace with**:
`$1:$2`

Set the **Regular Expressions** option, and click **Replace All**.

Note that if you also want to make all characters uppercase, replace with:

`\U$1:$2`

instead.

Comment: How is this different from my answer except yours doesn't work with Windows EOL?

Comment: This answer is for EmEditor.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, both use approx the same regex flavour. Once again, there're no differences from my answer except yours doesn't work with Windows EOL.

Comment: Mrt11234 asked this question for `Notepad++` or `EmEditor`. EmEditor does not understand `\R`, so that's why I added my answer.